# Creating factory but got conflicts with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

So, I'm building a factory handler for my node.js, express app. I'm using mongoose as my ODM. My factory handler is built with different functions and each one takes a model prop. It's wrapped with the catchAsync() function, which just catches the async issue. It was working till I used ts sctrict mode.

```
export const getAll = (model:Model<Document>) =>
  catchAsync(async (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    let query =  model.find();
    const doc = await query.select("-__v");
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      results: doc.length,
      data: doc,
    });
  });
```

here is my example model :

```
export const trackSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Trasa musi posiadać swoją nazwę"]
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Trasa musi posiadać swój opis"],
        min: [5, "Opis trasy musi mieć przynajmniej 5 znaków"],
        max: [500, `Opis przekroczył maksymalny ilośc znaków. (500)}`]
    },
    // tags: [TagSchema],
    thumbnail: String,
    //waypoints: [waypointSchema]
})
export type Track = InferSchemaType<typeof trackSchema> ;
const TrackModel = model<Track>('Tracks', trackSchema);
export default TrackModel;
```

here is how i implement it controller:

```
export const getAllTrack = getAll(TrackModel)
```

whole error messaage
Argument of type 'Model<{ name: string; description: string; waypoints: DocumentArray<{ name: string; type: string; explenation?: string | undefined; coords?: { label: string; lat: number; att: number; } | undefined; radius?: number | undefined; }>; thumbnail?: string | undefined; }, ... 4 more ..., any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model<Document<any, any, any>, {}, {}, {}, Document<unknown, {}, Document<any, any, any>> & Omit<Document<any, any, any> & { _id: ObjectId; }, never>, any>'.
The types returned by 'castObject(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type '{ name: string; description: string; waypoints: DocumentArray<{ name: string; type: string; explenation?: string | undefined; coords?: { label: string; lat: number; att: number; } | undefined; radius?: number | undefined; }>; thumbnail?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Document<any, any, any>'.ts(2345)